# Windows Forms Aplication-converting string to canvas drawing

Tags: c#, xml, canvas, windows-forms-designer

The following is all in c#:
I'm using various graphic methods to draw on a canvas(LevelPanel), which I then save to an XML file. I do so by converting it to a string:

```
 private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = FileNameBox.Text;

         Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(LevelPanel.Width, LevelPanel.Height);
         Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
         Rectangle rect = LevelPanel.RectangleToScreen(LevelPanel.ClientRectangle);
         g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, LevelPanel.Size);
         g.Dispose();
        string picString = "";

        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);
            picString = Convert.ToBase64String(m.ToArray());
            m.Close();
        }
        File.WriteAllText(@filename, picString);

    }
```

Is there any way I could load the file (take the string and convert it back to the image). I looked around, but couldn't find anything on this. Any help is gratefully recived. If it is impossible, could anybody suggest alternative methods of saving/loading the image as an xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just saving the XML with `File.WriteAllText("somefile.xml", picString);`

Read the xml like this

```
string base64String = File.ReadAllText("somefile.xml");
```

After reading the XML file you can convert it back to an image by calling this method

```
public static Image ImageFromBase64String(string base64String)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        return new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms, true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Loading it back into the pannel causes the system to run out of memory, I'm using  LevelPanel.BackgroundImage=Image. Compiles fine as before. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated the answer on this line `return new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms, true));` . But the out of memory is odd unless you're working with large images, don't forget to dispose your images after you're done using them.

Comment: Yeah, I was forgetting to dispose of them. But I'm not sure where to put the dispose command-if I use .Dispose() right after the load it gives me the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll and says the parameter is not valid.